# how do i use if buttons to trigger if statements in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, if-statement, ibaction

So i am creating a tic tac toe game (user vs computer) and i want to have -(IBAction) statements with if statements thats would say if(buttonIsPressed), do ____. I cant just say

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)selector;{
//stuff i want
}
```

because the buttons are pressed in different order and the computer would have different responses (i want there to be an order). For example, this is what i tried,

```
-(IBAction)move2;{

if (buttona2){
c2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgres-3.jpg"];
}
```

it didnt work because the the result of this if statement (  c2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgres-3.jpg"];) would start automatically and not run depending on the pressing of the button (it runs right away). Pretty much i want the if statement to run on press of a button (or not work if the button is not pressed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What you mean is `if (buttona2){` was *true*?  That's the question you need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to check if a button is toggled on or off before running the if statement right? In that case, I would declare a BOOL in your header file

```
@property BOOL toggle;
```

Then in your implementation file when the user presses the button the target of the button should have the code:

```
if(self.toggle == TRUE){
    self.toggle = FALSE; 
    //and any visual UI change you want to show that the button is now off
}else{
    self.toggle = TRUE;
    //and any visual change you want to show that the button is now on
}
```

Then in your `-(IBAction)` your code becomes:

```
-(IBAction)move2;{

    if (self.toggle){
        c2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgres-3.jpg"];
    }
}
```

And that should work.

Comment: For the first part why not get rid of the if else and simply use: self.toggle = !self.toggle;

Comment: I think because the user needs to do other stuff when value changes.

Comment: I like that! Never thought about it that way! It works if he doesn't want to make any changes apart from changing self.toggle value. If he wants to change for example the looks of the button or something he would have to go through the if function right? But love that! You have just saved me quite a few lines of code in the future.

Comment: Got asked: Thanks for the response. This makes sense, but i seem to be confused on how the bool statements "talks" with the UIButton. Like i am not sure how the bool statement receives input from the UIButton. How can I do this (sorry and i am new to this.)

Comment: Basically you use the BOOL statement to actually track whether the button is up or down... the UIButton merely allows for the function above to be run and acts as a visual representation of the BOOL statement @user3916985